# How can i using id obtained from first API call in another API call to get results in one button click in reactjs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

First i have to make a post request to get a id and then using that id i have to make other post request to get the result but this all need to happen in one button click using dataForSeo end point in reactjs ?

My code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Button, FormControl, InputGroup, Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

const App = () => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState('dataforseo.com');
  const [newId,setId] = useState("")
  const [results, setResults] = useState(null);

  const getDetails = async()=> {
    const post_array = [];
    post_array.push({
      newId,
    });
    console.log(newId);

    try {
      const username = process.env.REACT_APP_USERNAME;
      const password = process.env.REACT_APP_PASSWORD;
      const options = {
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://api.dataforseo.com/v3/on_page/pages',
        auth: {
          username,
          password
        },
        data: [{
          id : newId
        }],
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
      }
      const apiUrl = 'https://api.dataforseo.com/v3/on_page/pages';
      const response = await axios(apiUrl,options);

      setResults(response.data);
      console.log(response.data);   
     } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.response.data.status_message);
    }
  }

  const checkUrl = async () => {
    try {
      const username = process.env.REACT_APP_USERNAME;
      const password = process.env.REACT_APP_PASSWORD;
      const apiUrl = "https://api.dataforseo.com/v3/on_page/task_post";
      const response = await axios.post(apiUrl, {
        data: {
          url,
          enable_browser_rendering: true,
        },
      }, {
        auth: {
          username,
          password,
        },
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      });
      setId(response.data.tasks[0].id)
     }
       catch (error) {
      console.error(error.response.data);
    }
  };

  const getResult =async () => {
    await (checkUrl())
    console.log("First Completed!!")
      await getDetails()
      console.log("Second Completed!!")
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <h1>DataForSEO URL Checker</h1>
          <InputGroup className="mb-3">
            <FormControl
              placeholder="Enter URL"
              value={url}
              onChange={(e) => setUrl(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={()=>{getResult()}}>Check</Button>
          </InputGroup>
          {results && (
            <div>
              <h2>Results:</h2>
              <pre>{JSON.stringify(results, null, 2)}</pre>
            </div>
          )}
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Is it Matrix? I am seeing a glitch. Kidding aside just make two API calls with axios.